# crosstab query can have date in where condition?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I am using crosstab query for my data. But now I need to filter date according to date and then convert it in crosstab. But I think it is not possible. I also read postgresql documentation but didn't found anything related to it.Can anyone confirm that? Below is the query that I am trying to run but gives error:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT a.name, al.type, COALESCE(sum(a.amt),0) as amt FROM account a where date(a.vdate)>='07-30-2017' and date(a.vdate)<='08-31-2017' group by a.name, a.type order by a.name',$$VALUES ('type1'), ('type2')$$) AS ct ("name" text,  "type1" decimal, "type2" decimal))
```

When I am using without date in where part it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried double-quoting the filtering date?
`SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT a.name, al.type, COALESCE(sum(a.amt),0) as amt FROM account a where date(a.vdate)>=''07-30-2017'' and date(a.vdate)<=''08-31-2017'' group by a.name, a.type order by a.name',$$VALUES ('type1'), ('type2')$$) AS ct ("name" text,  "type1" decimal, "type2" decimal))`

Comment: Thank you so much :) it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dollar-quotes for the first query like you've done for the second one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab($$
    SELECT a.name, a.type, COALESCE(sum(a.amt),0) as amt 
    FROM account a 
    WHERE date(a.vdate)>='07-30-2017' and date(a.vdate)<='08-31-2017' 
    GROUP BY a.name, a.type 
    ORDER BY a.name
    $$,
    $$
    VALUES ('type1'), ('type2')
    $$
) AS ct ("name" text,  "type1" decimal, "type2" decimal);
```

Comment: Can I add variable instead of static date?

Comment: Essentially postgresql knows no variables. Of course, you can apply variables in your client program when generating the query, or you can use an auxiliary table, depending on what you expect. I think you could ask a new question with a more detailed description of the issue.

Comment: Thanks klin :) I had applied variable in java where I generated this query.